# Not to terminate Ajax request even after page change in laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am having a view file on which I want to send Ajax request to my controller route, there I have used
ignore_user_abort(True);
This is not working for me,

That request can take up to 1 hour,
Hence if user leaves the page, How can I keep ajax request running in it?
I have turned on ignore_user_abort in php.ini

It was working before some days ago, But not working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a script that takes a long time to execute, you can use Queue: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues

Using queue, it will run your script in the background.